# 顧客満足率 95% に達成するためには、あといくつの"満足"という回答が必要か知りたい

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Google Spreadsheet を社内の表計算ソフトとして使っている者です。
最近 JS を書き始めたばかりで、早速てこずっていることがあります。

[まずはこちらのシートの確認をお願いします](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1lXmj58npRwBU7DdONYRulTb8wwoXyLzcYXferx93thQ/edit#gid=99734622)
顧客満足率(満足の回答数 / 回答合計) が95%に達成するためには、
あといくつの「満足の回答数」が必要かを求めるのが Goal です。
(※目標達成までは「不満足の回答」が入らないことを前提とする)

```js
function myFunction() {
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Test");
  var curfb = ss.getRange("A2").getValue(); //200
  var curcs = ss.getRange("B2").getValue(); //150

  while (curcs/curfb < 0.95)
  {

}


}
```

↑ここまでやったのですが、恥ずかしながらこれ以上はどうすればいいのか見当もつかず、、、

Answer (score 1, accepted):

現在の回答合計をT0
現在の満足回答をX0
必要な満足回答をxとすると、

0.95=(X0+x)/(T0+x)  ですので、
0.95(T0+x)=X0+x
0.95T0+0.95x=X0+x
0.95T0-X0=x-0.95x
0.95T0-X0=0.05x
x = (0.95T0-X0)/0.05 = (95T0-100X0)/5 = 19T0-20X0
例えば、現在の回答合計が２００、現在の満足回答を１５０の場合、
１９＊２００－２０＊１５０ ＝ ３８００－３０００＝８００で
８００の満足回答が必要となります。
（（１５０＋８００）／（２００＋８００）＝９５０／１０００＝０．９５）